# Image in php index.php file

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to insert an image in the image2 class as shown down below in the code. I have tried many different things but i get a "?" every time.

The picture is uploaded in the same web hotel as my site runs on.

directory file: /www/wp-content/themes/jonas/images/meg.jpg

This is the index.php file for my wordpress theme.

The code is posted on http://www.vetlesen.no

```
<?php

get_header();
?>


<div class="intro-tekst">
<h1>HI, IM A DESIGN STUDENT FROM NORWAY</h1>

<h3>Scroll down for work:-)</h3>


    <div class="image2">

    <!-- I want to insert "meg.jpg" image here -->

    </div>


</div>


<?php
if (have_posts()) :
  while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="wrap">
  <article class="post">
   <h2 class="overskrift"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
      <?php the_content(); ?>

    </article>

</div>

  <?php endwhile;

  else :
    echo "<p>No content found</p>";

  endif;


get_footer();

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [`get_site_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_site_url/) function try this :

```
    get_header();
    ?>


    <div class="intro-tekst">
    <h1>HI, IM A DESIGN STUDENT FROM NORWAY</h1>

    <h3>Scroll down for work:-)</h3>


        <div class="image2">

        <img src="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/jonas/images/meg.jpg"  />

        </div>


    </div>


    <?php
    if (have_posts()) :
      while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="wrap">
      <article class="post">
       <h2 class="overskrift"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
          <?php the_content(); ?>

        </article>

    </div>

      <?php endwhile;

      else :
        echo "<p>No content found</p>";

      endif;


    get_footer();

     ?>
```

Comment: I have a problem resizing the image in css with witdh and height. Any idea?

Comment: use this class in you custom stylesheet `.intro-tekst img{ width:youwidth px; }`

Comment: great, you are a legend!